# Ember nested global routes (Wildcard)

Tags: ember.js, routes, nested, wildcard, glob

I'm trying to do something like this in my routes:

```
this.route('products', { path: "/products/*choises"}, function() {
   this.route('promotion', {path: "/promotion/*offers"});
});
```

product route:

```
    offerPath: function(params){
      this.transitionTo('product.promotion', params);
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't matter the promotion that I visit, the app thinks is part of the products route.
How can I do this? I need them to be nested.

Comment: are choices product ids?

Comment: The short answer is you can't because the glob is greedy and will match everything up to the end of the path, like you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
You can use `beforeModel(transition)` hook in router to check what's in the url.

http://example.com/products/manufacturer-209/series-881/tag-17143/none/494822/f‌​lawless

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  beforeModel(transition) {
    console.log(transition.params.products.choises)
   // if you use this url: http://example.com/products/manufacturer-209/series-881/tag-17143/none/494822/f‌​lawless
   // console log would be: "manufacturer-209/series-881/tag-17143/none/494822/f‌​lawless"
  }

});
```

At least you have the rest of the url so, you can filter out the important information and redirect with `this.transitionTo()` to the exact place.

---

You could have the following route:

```
http://example.com/products/123/promotions/456
```

or

```
http://example.com/products/awesome_souce/promotions/monday_deal
```

In the first case, your route would look like this:

```
this.route('product', { path: "/products/:product_id"}, function() {
  this.route('promotion', {path: "/promotions/:promotion_id"});
});
```

In the second case, maybe like this:

```
this.route('product', { path: "/products/:product_name"}, function() {
  this.route('promotion', {path: "/promotions/:promotion_name"});
});
```

Finally, your route handlers can download the proper models (example for the first case):

```
// app/routes/product.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('product', params.product_id);
  }
});

---

// app/routes/product/promotion.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    // you can get access to the parent route model if you need for the api query
    const product = this.modelFor('product');
    return this.store.findRecord('promotion', params.promotion_id);
  }
});
```

If you need only the param from the `product` route, instead of returning a whole record, for example you can just `return params.product_name`, so you will have access to a string with `this.modelFor('product')` in a subroute level.

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! The probem is that my routes are more complex.
For example, for a product:
      `http://example.com/products/manufacturer-209/series-881/tag-17143/none/494822/flawless`

And for an offer:
`http://example.com/products/manufacturer-209/series-881/tag-17143/none/494822/flawless/promotions/494822-flawless-working`

I've nested the routes and it works great, but when I reload the promotion url, the app things I'm in the product route

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was looking